# What are the relations and differences between Implication, inference rule and equivalence in logic?

Tags: logic, computer-science, first-order-logic

In [first order predicate logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Formation_rules), implication is an operator on formulas

> If $φ$ and $ψ$ are formulas, then $φ  \rightarrow ψ$ is a formula.

We also have that if formulas $P_1$ implies $P_2$  and  $P_2$ implies $P_3$, then  $P_1$ implies $P_3$, i.e.,

```
1  → 2 
2  → 3
---------
1  → 3
```

Is the above considered as a inference rule? or a formula `(1  → 2) ∧ (2  → 3)  → (1  → 3)`? Why is it considered as one but not the other?

We also have that

```
(P1 → P2) ≡ ( ¬P1 ∨ P 2)
(¬∃X [P(X)]) ≡ (∀X [ ¬P(X)])
¬ (P1 ∧ P2) ≡ (¬P1 ∨ ¬P2)
```

Are the above three considered as three formulas, or as some equivalence relation between formulas? Why are they considered as one but not the other?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $\to$ is indeed used for *material implication*: it is a logical operator and combines two logic expression into a larger logic expression. It has a semantics as provided by its truth-table, that I am sure you are familiar with.

On the other hand, the $\Rightarrow$ is typically used for *logical implication*.  This symbol is a *meta-logical* symbol.  It does not combine two logic statements into one larger logic statement, and it does not have a truth-table.  Rather, it says something *about* those two logic statements.  $P1 \Rightarrow P2$ says that $P2$ is a logical consequence of $P1$:  that it is impossible for $P1$ to be true and $P2$ to be false at the same time.

Example:  $P \land Q \Rightarrow P$ is true, since it is impossible for $P \land Q$ to be true but $P$ to be false. On the other hand we do *not* have that $P \Rightarrow Q$: it is possible for $P$ to be true and $Q$ to be false. How is this different from $P \to Q$?  Well, I could symbolize: 'If there is smoke, then there is fire' with $P \to Q$ ... so that would be my way of saying that *in the particular world I am trying to describe*, $P \to Q$ is true.  But, since there are also logically possible worlds where you can have smoke without fire, we do not have that $P \Rightarrow Q$

Sometimes we use $P \vDash Q$ to represent the same logical implication relationship ... though we often use $\vDash$ using sets of statements.  So, with your example, we could say:

$$\{ P1 \to P2, P2 \to P3 \} \vDash P1 \to P3$$

though we can conjunct the statements from the implying set of statements into a single statement, and thus say:

$$( P1 \to P2) \land (P2 \to P3) \Rightarrow P1 \to P3$$

Now, here is an interesting relationship between $\to$ and $\Rightarrow$:  $P1 \Rightarrow P2$ is true if and only if $P1 \to P2$ is a logical tautology (i.e. always true when evaluated on a truth-table). So, for the above example, we can say that $$(( P1 \to P2) \land (P2 \to P3)) \to (P1 \to P3)$$ is a logical tautology. By the way, we can write $\Rightarrow P$ or $\vDash P$ to indicate that $P$ is a tautology, i.e. we have:

$$P1 \Rightarrow P2 \text{ if and only if } \Rightarrow (P1 \to P2)$$

Of course, you can take any fact of logical consequence, and turn it into an inference rule. Thus, we can indeed say that:

$$P1 \to P2$$

$$P2 \to P3$$

$$ \therefore P1 \to P3$$

is an inference rule, and many textbooks do exactly that, calling it Hypothetical Syllogism or Chain Argument.  To indicate it is a rule of inference for some formal proof system, though, we typically use the $\vdash$ symbol. In this case, we would say:

$$P1 \to P2, P2 \to P3 \vdash P1 \to P3$$

or

$$\{ P1 \to P2, P2 \to P3 \} \vdash P1 \to P3$$

Perversely, you can define anything an inference rule. If I wanted to, I could say that:

$$P$$

$$\therefore P \land Q$$

is an inference rule, and call it "Modus Bogus"

I would thus write $$P \vdash P \land Q$$

Note that of course this is *not* a *valid* inference rule, because it is *not* true that $$P \vDash P \land Q$$

Finally, the three formulas at the bottom of your post *could be* seen as single logic formulas, *if* we treat the $\equiv$ as the symbol for the *material* biconditional operator. As such, they would all be tautologies.  But, most likely they are used as *logical equivalence* symbols, i.e. as *meta-logical* symbols that state that the statement on the left is logically equivalent to the statement on the right.  For this, however, we typically use $\Leftrightarrow$

Some further connections:  We have that for any statements $P1$ and $P2$:

$$P1 \leftrightarrow P2 \Leftrightarrow (P1 \to P2) \land (P2 \to P1)$$

and thus also that:

$$\Rightarrow (P1 \leftrightarrow P2) \leftrightarrow ((P1 \to P2) \land (P2 \to P1))$$

And as a really nice mix up of three different uses of 'if and only if', we have:

$$P1 \Leftrightarrow P2 \text{ if and only if } \Rightarrow P1 \leftrightarrow P2$$

So yes, it is all pretty confusing, and to make matters worse, there is no strict standard on the use of these symbols: some textbooks use $\Rightarrow$ for the material conditional/implication, while others use it for the logical implication.  Likewise, some textbooks use $\Leftrightarrow$ for the material biconditional, while others use it for the logical equivalence.  And, some textbooks use $\equiv$ for the material biconditional, while others use it for the logical equivalence.

Comment: Thanks. "the three formulass at the bottom of your post could be seen as single logic formulas, if we treat the  as the symbol for the material biconditional operator. As such, they would all be tautologies. But, most likely they are used as logical equivalence symbols". Does logical equivalence mean exactly logical implication in both directions?

Comment: @Tim Correct!  I should have pointed that out in my answer. But yes, two statements are logically equivalent if and only if they logically imply each other. In Metalogic notation: $P1 \Leftrightarrow p2$ if and only if $P1 \Rightarrow P2$ and $P2\Rightarrow P1$